Byte order from Modbus request
I'm trying to read out a Modbus register over TCP, which seems to be working fine, however the response and the byte order are not making sense to me. I'm using JavaScript and the jsModbus library to read it out.
According to the documentation, the register I'm reading is a Float32 and is BigEndian.
The value I'm expecting is 100.
When I get the response, the literal buffer is [0,0,66,200]
When trying out some things locally, the ordering does not really make sense at all to me, I simply do not understand what is happening exactly.
I tried creating the buffers locally to see and compare byte ordering.
> let buffer = Buffer.alloc(4);
undefined
> buffer.writeFloatBE(100);
4
> console.log(buffer)
<Buffer 42 c8 00 00>
undefined
> buffer.writeFloatLE(100);
4
> console.log(buffer)
<Buffer 00 00 c8 42>
undefined
> let received = Buffer.from([0,0,66,200])
undefined
> console.log(received);
<Buffer 00 00 42 c8>
undefined
> received.swap32()
<Buffer c8 42 00 00>
> received.readFloatBE()
-198656

I also tried swapping the bytes (32) as according to the Buffer docs, a float is 32 bytes, but that also gives me the invalid result.
The only way I got the 'valid' response, was by first doing a swap16, then a swap32 but that makes even less sense to me.

This is a useful tool in situations like this, entering your data (00 00 42 C8) shows that it's probably a "Float - Mid-Little Endian (CDAB)" (a fairly common encoding). As such Buffer.from([0,0,66,200]).swap16().readFloatLE(0) is probably (depends on system endianess) what you need.

That tool is really helpful! I did not know mid-little endian was something that existed and the documentation stating it's Big Endian threw me off completely.
I did end up actually doing that after swapping around a lot, doing a swap16 and reading little endian and it does give the expected value, thank you!
